# How do I add items to ASINList list?

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I am trying out the Amazon MWS samples. How do I initialise request.ASINList with a list of ASINs?

My ASINs are in strings.

```
// Create a request.
GetLowestOfferListingsForASINRequest request = new GetLowestOfferListingsForASINRequest();
string sellerId = "example";
request.SellerId = sellerId;
string mwsAuthToken = "example";
request.MWSAuthToken = mwsAuthToken;
string marketplaceId = "example";
request.MarketplaceId = marketplaceId;
ASINListType asinList = new ASINListType();
request.ASINList = asinList;
string itemCondition = "example";
request.ItemCondition = itemCondition;
bool excludeMe = true;
request.ExcludeMe = excludeMe;
return this.client.GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN(request);
```

I can't seem to implicitly or explicitly cast a list or array of strings to ASINListType.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know c# but in PHP you have to create an object of class "MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType"
e.g.

```
$asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
$asin_list->setASIN($asin_array);
$request->setASINList($asin_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `request.ASINList` needs to be assigned to an `ASINListType`.  So instantiate that object, and assign your ASINs to it's ASIN property.  This is just one way of doing it, but I typically do it very quickly this way:

```
var asinListType = new ASINListType();
asinListType.ASIN = new List<string> { "B00005TQI7", "B00AVO5XRK", etc, etc };
request.ASINList = asinListType;
```